# Getting exception Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: Only TabItem instances can be added to TabLayout in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, tabbedpage

I'm getting the exception

```
Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: Only TabItem instances can be added to TabLayout
```

This is my XAML code-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:RestaurantApp"
            x:Class="RestaurantApp.SearchTabbedPage">
  <!--Pages can be added as references or inline-->
    <TabbedPage.Children>
        <NavigationPage Title="VENDOR NAME">
            <x:Arguments>
                <pages:TabbedPageExampleTab1 />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>

        <NavigationPage Title="PRODUCT/SERVICE">
            <x:Arguments>
                <pages:TabbedPageExampleTab2 />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </TabbedPage.Children>
</TabbedPage>
```

This is my code behind code

```
  namespace RestaurantApp
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class SearchTabbedPage : TabbedPage
    {
        public SearchTabbedPage ()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
    }
}
```

This is the app.xaml.cs code

```
 public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = new SearchTabbedPage();


            //};
        }
```

This is xaml code of TabbedPageExampleTab1

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="RestaurantApp.TabbedPageExampleTab1">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Hello. I am Judson" Margin="5" />


        <Label Text="You are on Tab one"></Label>

        <BoxView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Color="Silver"></BoxView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

This is the code behind

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class TabbedPageExampleTab1 : ContentPage
    {
        public TabbedPageExampleTab1 ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
        }
    }
```

this same code is being followed for TabbedPageExampleTab2 as well.

This is the UI I need

[image]

I don't have any clue why I'm getting this exception. Any suggestions.
[This is the google drive link for the zipped file of the project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZBoD08d4wK0p8MFCh1ajvIYSkxUg0lSJ/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I think here `Children.Add(new ContentPage());`, you should add `ContentPage` type like `Page1` or `EmployePage` etc instead of direct `ConentPage`

Comment: yeah I tried that as well

Comment: I'll edit the code behind code

Comment: How many pages you have to add in TabbedPage, Can you please mention those names in question like I need to add page1, page2 etc.

Comment: @CGPA6.4 I have given reference to TabbedPageExampleTab1 but still it gives me the same exception.

Comment: I need to add two pages

Comment: I'll put the screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code to add page in `TabbedPage`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:RestaurantApp"
            x:Class="RestaurantApp.SearchTabbedPage">
    <TabbedPage.Children>
        <NavigationPage Title="VENDOR NAME">
            <x:Arguments>
                <pages:TabbedPageExampleTab1 />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>

        <NavigationPage Title="Product/Service">
            <x:Arguments>
                <pages:TabbedPageExampleTab2 />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </TabbedPage.Children>
</TabbedPage>
```

Your `SearchTabbedPage` should be empty, mean no need to use this line

```
Children.Add(new TabbedPageExampleTab1());
```

**Edit:** Your Tabbar.xaml file should look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" 
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabMode="fixed">    
</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```

Do not add `TextView` inside it.

Comment: You should not add Tab in again in `SearchTabbedPage.cs`. Your pages `TabbedPageExampleTab1` or `TabbedPageExampleTab2` should be inherited with `ContentPage`.

Comment: Yeah, I have done that as well. I'll put my latest code now.

Comment: bottom tabs are TabbedPageExampleTab1 and TabbedPageExampleTab2 as you can see

Comment: And I have set the tabbed page as initial page as you can see in my app.xaml.cs code

Comment: If possible provide my zip repository of project. So that I'll check what exactly happening.

Comment: K sure @CGPA6.4

Comment: I have added a google drive link to the zip file of the project please have a look.